# Portable version of Onedrive desktop app

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, portable-apps

Is there a portable version of Onedrive desktop app for windows like the [DropboxPortableAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/) for dropbox ?

Comment: No; There isn’t.  What you want isn’t possible

Comment: No, but you can use WebDAV to map OneDrive folders. They do not sync to your computer but you can access them more or less the same way. I actually wish there was WebDAV for Dropbox so I don't need to use DBP to access Dropbox files.

Comment: hello @InterLinked... can you supply some examples/recipes to connect webdav to OneDrive folders?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, commenting seems broken now on the site, so here it is as an answer.

While not quite portable in that your files are not actually stored portably at all, you can use WebDAV to access your files without download them at all. This basically presents it to you as a network drive, as if the files were on a network server on your LAN.

1. In your web browser, login to your OneDrive.
2. After you log in, your URL should be like:
   https://onedrive.live.com/?id=root&cid=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
   The ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP part is your “customer ID”. Select it and copy it to the clipboard.
3. Map "https://d.docs.live.net/CUSTOMERID" in Explorer. You do this as you would map any network drive.

Be sure to not check "Reconnect at login" if the computer isn't yours.

If it is yours, you can automate this by using a batch script using the `net use` command:

e.g. map "Documents", require password interactively, do not reconnect at login:

`net use h: "https://d.docs.live.net/CUSTOMERID/Documents" /user:myuser@outlook.com /P:no`

e.g. with the password, non-interactive, reconnect automatically:

`net use h: "https://d.docs.live.net/CUSTOMERID/Documents" /user:myuser@outlook.com mypassword /P:Yes`

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-onedrive-network-drive

Comment: After following steps, it worked, but mapped drive is not showing in windows explorer but in cmd

Comment: It won't show up in existing explorer windows, you will need to open a new one. Are you possibly running in an admin command prompt? Without linked connections, it would not show up, either. Make sure UAC is on and you are running in a non-elevated prompt